# How do you efficiently subset data for charts (e.g., boxplots) in R?

Tags: r, boxplot

I researched this question quite a bit and apologies if I missed an answer but I can't seem to find an answer specific to my scenario. I would like to create 2 charts (for each level  Account:Dr and Cr) with 6 box plots each based off of data in three columns. The data is similar to the data below (assume there are six dates;01/01/2016-06/01/2016):

```
 Date         Days     Acct
 01/01/16     7        Cr  
 01/01/16     5        Dr  
 02/01/16     6        Cr 
 01/01/16     4        Dr
 02/01/16     6        Dr
```

And let's assume that goes on for a 1,000 rows with only 6 unique Date values and two Account values--Cr and Dr. I'll explain what I did to get the chart, but I know it's not the most efficient manner, because I am at the moment using a for loop.

I assigned the Cr data to one data frame, then the Dr data to another data frame. Then I assigned the unique Date values from each data frame to new data frames. After that, I run a For loop to create a data frame for each Date value and assign the Day values to each as shown below:

```
01/01/2016 (Data Frame 1, col A)   
5                                   
7                                   
6

02/01/2016 (Data Frame 2, col A)
3
5
```

Then I run a cbind.fill to combine all the data frames into one with 6 columns where the Date is the header and the Days are the values in the rows. The I run a boxplot on that data frame.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so I hope I am interpreting your question correctly. You want two charts (1 for each level of Acct), each chart should have six boxplots (one box per Date). Since your dataset wasn't big enough to use as an example, I created my own and show how to make the boxplots using `ggplot2` and base `R`.

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(123)
date_vec = seq(as.Date('2016/1/1'), as.Date('2016/1/6'), by = 'day')
df = data.frame(
  Date = sample(date_vec, 1000, replace = T),
  Days = rpois(1000, lambda = 2),
  Acct = sample(c('Dr','Cr'), 1000, replace = T),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
        Date Days Acct
1 2016-01-02    1   Dr
2 2016-01-05    2   Dr
3 2016-01-03    1   Dr
4 2016-01-06    3   Cr
5 2016-01-06    3   Dr
6 2016-01-01    2   Cr
```

You could use `ggplot2` and `facet_wrap` by `Acct`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(Date), y = Days))+
  geom_boxplot()+facet_wrap(~Acct)+theme_bw()+
  xlab('Date')
```

[image]

Or, we can make a two panel boxplot in base `R`:

```
par(mfrow = c(1,2)) #plot both simultaneously
with(subset(df, Acct == 'Cr'),
     boxplot(Days~Date, main = 'Cr Boxplots'))
with(subset(df, Acct == 'Dr'),
     boxplot(Days~Date, main = 'Dr Boxplots'))
```

[image]

Obviously, you would need to play around with the x-axis labels to have a more informative chart. I hope this helps.

Comment: Wow! There is obviously a lot I need to learn about R still! Thanks, bouncyball! Was I correct that there isn't much online about this scenario or did I just not research it correctly?

Comment: I think if you spent some time looking at some `R` functions like `with`, `subset`, and the `*apply` class of functions it might help you out. Of course SO is always a great resource, too!